# How many players in the 2018 Stanley Cup finals have won a finals game before?

Tags: trivia, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

The Washington Capitals and the Las Vegas Golden Knights have made it to 2017-18 Stanley Cup finals. Neither team has won a Stanley cup final game before. Of all the NHL players in [the 2018 Finals game 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Stanley_Cup_Finals), **how many have won at least one game in a Stanley Cup Final game before?**

Comment: Aside: [FiveThirtyEight have covered a *very* similar question to this](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-caps-and-knights-might-have-the-least-experienced-stanley-cup-final-rosters-ever/).

Comment: @PhilipKendall That's a great answer two days after this question was posted. You could copy and paste summary points into an answer here.

Comment: It's not actually your question as 538's is how many players have *played* in a Stanley Cup Final game whereas yours is how many have *won* a Stanley Cup Final game.

Comment: @PhilipKendall The reason I narrowed my question is I knew Washington got swept by Detroit the only time they were in the Stanley Cup Playoffs in their franchise history.

Answer (score 2):

[Brooks Orpik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks_Orpik) playing for Washington Capitals won Stanley Cup in [2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Stanley_Cup_Finals) with Pittsburgh Penguins.

Vegas goaltender [Marc-André Fleury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc-Andr%C3%A9_Fleury) won three Stanley Cups - also with Penguins - in [2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Stanley_Cup_Finals), [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Stanley_Cup_Finals) and [2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Stanley_Cup_Finals).

Both Orpik and Fleury also played in [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Stanley_Cup_Finals), where Penguins lost to Detroit Red Wings.

In the [2017 Stanley Cup Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Stanley_Cup_Finals), [James Neal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Neal_(ice_hockey)) played for Nashville Predators, Predators lost the series to Penguins 2-4. He also currently plays for Vegas Golden Knights.

This should be all players with previous Stanley Cup final appearances from the rosters of the the two finalists according to sources below and also according to the Wikipedia article [2018 Stanley Cup Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Stanley_Cup_Finals). (Here is link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2018_Stanley_Cup_Finals&action=history). Notice the column "Finals appearance" in the section [Team rosters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Stanley_Cup_Finals#Team_rosters).)

- [NHL Morning Skate: Stanley Cup Final Edition – May 27, 2018](https://media.nhl.com/public/news/12133?utm_source=morning-skate&utm_medium=twitter&sf88859652=1)
- [Golden Knights leaning on Fleury, Neal heading into Stanley Cup Final](https://www.nhl.com/news/vegas-golden-knights-leaning-on-fleury-neal-heading-into-stanley-cup-final/c-298801796)
- [Ex-Penguins Brooks Orpik, Marc-Andre Fleury know Cup success](http://triblive.com/sports/penguins/13685912-74/ex-penguins-brooks-orpik-marc-andre-fleury-know-cup-success)
- [Brooks Orpik is only Capital with Stanley Cup finals experience: ‘A big role model’](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/capitals-insider/wp/2018/05/26/brooks-orpik-is-only-capitals-player-with-stanley-cup-experience-hes-a-big-role-model/?utm_term=.8a37279bc976)

Comment: So the answer is three players have won in a Stanley Cup Final Game before (but necessarily won the cup): Orpik, Fluery and Neal? The other 50-odd players are looking for first win. (As of this time it's half that because Vegas won last night). Is this low number history making?